# not able to parse optional option in java

Tags: java

I have following code:

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws ParseException{

    Options options = new Options();
    options.addOption("g", "delimiter", false, "default delim is ,");

    CommandLineParser parser = new PosixParser();
    CommandLine cmd = parser.parse(options, args);
    String input = cmd.getOptionValue("g");
    System.out.println(input);

}
```

In my runtime config, I have these args

```
-g @
```

What I am expecting to see is `"@"` but the output is `null`?

What am i missing?
Thanks

Comment: You didn't specify what utilities you're using. Is this Commons-CLI? Does this work for any other values besides `@`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `g` option requires an argument, Changing the third parameter in option from `false` to `true` works.

```
options.addOption("g", "delimiter", true, "default delim is ,");
```

I have changed from `false` to `true` since option `g` requires an argument if it's passed in command line. It works fine then.

This is from their java doc

> The addOption method has three parameters. The first parameter is a java.lang.String that represents the option. The second parameter is a boolean that specifies whether the option requires an argument or not. In the case of a boolean option (sometimes referred to as a flag) an argument value is not present so false is passed. The third parameter is the description of the option. This description will be used in the usage text of the application.

Comment: Assuming you are using commons-cli. ;)